# Wordpress: cloaking links

Tags: wordpress, redirect, cloaking

I am cloaking my affiliate link in wordpress and I don't want my user to see it in the status bar or something so is there a way for me to go to a page like www.mysite.com/my-redirect.php?p=foo without me having to create a page or post? or is there a better way?

My redirect.php file will do the redirection after the user lands to this file.

I am using the latest version.

Comment: Why are you cloaking this for your users? That's lying and I don't think your users will like that.

Comment: I would heavily advice against cloaking affiliate links.  It's dishonest, unethical, and will only breed negative sentiment towards you and your site in the market.

Comment: I apologize to you guys for not clearing my question. Actually, the "user" i mean is my competitors. If I let them see my affiliate link then they'll have an idea where to get the offers I am promoting. I swear that I don't do things that can ruin my reputation and lie to my customers. Also I am running my traffic from Adwords so I think if I am doing something to trick my customers then they will most likely terminate my account. Again I apologize.

Comment: Nah, don't listen to them. If you want to turn an ugly affiliate link into nice looking permalink thats your business, and a matter of aesthetics. If you want to not prematurely reveal that a product your advertising, and they are interested in, is an amazon associated product, then you have every right and are justified for enahcing your procedure, by removing a potential point of bailing, or worse, giving them the opportunity to spite your affiliate link by removing the tracking tag due to some prejudice (Which does happen).

Comment: I apologizes for saying not to listen to them, thats going to far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to create a masked link, which is a unique link that appear to be embedded into your internal link structure, but really is an offsite redirect.  A masked link looks something like http://www.myblog.com/recommendeds/wp-traffic-tools/

There are a couple of commercial solutions including:
WP Traffic Tools
Eclipse Link Cloaker
WP Link Engine

And I believe there are some free tools around but due to all the starch in the topic they are not available in the Wordpress Plugin Database, but are available elsewhere. PlanetOzh I believe has a free one floating around.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is use the Urban Giraffe Redirection plugin to create a redirection in my blog to the affiliate link. i.e. say you're going to the link "http://blah.someproduct.clickbank.net", you can use Redirection to create a mapping for "/go/blah" to that link. Pretty easy stuff. Plus you can track how many times the link was clicked in the blog.

http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to hide affiliate links is using the free generator made by Clevious. [You can find it here](https://www.clevious.com/2019/01/auto-cloak-affiliate-links-free.html)

It will allow you to hide all your affiliate links automatically and without doing anything.

Many plugins offer that functionality as premium, but you can have it for free.

All you have to do is entering some information like the platform you are using: Blogger or WordPress, and you would probably exclude some links from being cloaked and there you go, by clicking on generate code, your code will be generated.

For installation, you just need to follow the quick and easy instructions below the generated code.

Good luck.